# Не получается организовать асинхронное чтение в режиме клиента по TCP в boost::asio

Tags: c++, сеть, boost, asio

Пишу асинхронный клиент на boost::asio, весь день не получается принять данные по TCP от сервера.

```
using namespace boost::asio;

streambuf readbuf(1024);

size_t read_complete(const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t bytes) {
    std::cout << endl << "read_complete turn. { \n err: " << err.message() << endl << "bytes: " << bytes << "\n}" << std::endl;
    return 0;
};

void on_read(const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t bytes) {
    std::cout << endl << "on_read turn. { \n err: " << err.message() << endl << "bytes: " << bytes << "\n}" << std::endl;
    if (!err) {
        std::cout << "server echoed our " << "FAIL" << std::endl;
    }
};

void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
    std::cout << "connect_handler." << std::endl;
    cout << ec.value();
    cout << ec.message();
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus"); // вызов функции настройки локали
    io_service service;
    ip::tcp::socket sock_(service);
    ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string("64.253.153.64"), 3000);
    sock_.async_connect(ep, connect_handler);
    service.run();
    async_read(sock_, readbuf, read_complete, on_read);
    sock_.send(buffer(reg_pack, sizeof reg_pack));
    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
        async_read(sock_, readbuf, read_complete, on_read);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Точно знаю, что на этот сокет приходят данные от сервера (смотрю в Wireshark) но при вызове read_complete в параметре size_t bytes всегда приходит 0. Как мне правильно забрать полученные данные (интересует именно что я не так делаю а не ссылки на другие решения)?

#### UPD: Изменённый код с service.run_one().

```
streambuf readbuf(1024);
io_service service;
ip::tcp::socket sock_(service);
ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string("64.253.153.64"), 3000);

void on_read(const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t bytes) {
    std::cout << endl << "on_read turn. { \n err: " << err.message() << endl << "bytes: " << bytes << "\n}" << std::endl;
    if (!err) {
        std::cout << "server echoed our " << "FAIL" << std::endl;
    }
};

size_t read_complete(const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t bytes) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    async_read(sock_, readbuf, read_complete, on_read);
    std::cout << endl << "read_complete turn. { \n err: " << err.message() << endl << "bytes: " << bytes << "\n}" << std::endl;
    service.run_one();
    return 0;
};

void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
    std::cout << "connect_handler." << std::endl;
    cout << ec.value();
    cout << ec.message();
    async_read(sock_, readbuf, read_complete, on_read);
    service.run_one();
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus"); // вызов функции настройки локали

    sock_.async_connect(ep, connect_handler);
    service.run();
    //async_read(sock_, readbuf, read_complete, on_read);
    sock_.send(buffer(reg_pack, sizeof reg_pack));

    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1000));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так чтения не происходит, у вас явно не хватает вызовов `service.run_one_for();` после запросов на  чтение.

Comment: @VTT а service.run() не заставляет слушать сокет всё время, или нужно после каждого чтения вызывать service.run_one_for() отдельно?

Comment: Она слушает сокет, пока у нее есть обработчики. После срабатывания `connect_handler` она вернется и обработчики на чтение сами по себе вызываться не будут.

Comment: @VTT добавил service.run_one(), что нужно изменить что бы заработало?

Comment: @VTT разобрался благодаря вашим подсказкам, спасибо вам большое. Можете что ни будь написать про service.run_one() в ответы, что бы я пометил ваш ответ как ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Ваши обработчики (`handlers`) имеют как минимум один аргумент, соответственно, необходимо связать функцию с объектом:

```
boost::bind(connect_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error)
```

У вас нарушен принцип асинхронного подхода. Код не когда не выйдет из метода `io_service::run()`. Соответственно, вы предварительно должны связать обработчик подключения (`connect_handler`). Внутри `connect_handler` должна произойти связь обработчика записи (`on_write`). Соответственно внутри `on_write` связь обработчика чтения (`on_read`). Таким образом мы получаем цепочку: `connect-> write-> read-> write-> read-> ...-> disconnect`

[Вот](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp) хороший пример. Не обращайте внимание на SSL, вам главное уловить суть асинхронной парадигмы.

Comment: Разве функции, функторы и замыкания не взаимозаменяемы? Я думал, что bind нужна только что бы превратить произвольный метод произвольного класса в функтор и всегда считал что где можно применять функторы из std там точно так же можно применить функции или замыкания (или я не прав?). Что касается connect-> write-> read-> write-> read-> то мне не нужна такая цепочка. В моей задаче чтение и запись полностью спонтанны. Я сначала взял синхронные варианты и у меня всё хорошо заработало. Но я не смог полностью перекрыть мьютексом сокет (чтение морозит поток и мьютек остаётся захваченным).

Comment: Но я обязательно почитаю и попробую. Большое вам спасибо.

Comment: @mrFieldy, bind нужен, что бы функцию / метод вида void foo(int bar) привести к виду void foo(int bar = 10). Это пример не совсем корректен, но понятен. В вашем случае, io_service не имеет представления какой объект отдавать handler-у в виде аргумента, а bind ему в этом помогает.

Comment: я всё же думаю что bind был создан для создания функтора, а как его можно использовать это другой вопрос. В моём случае я попробовал отправлять в  io_service и функцию и функтор и замыкания, и во всех трёх случаях io_service отработал корректно. Как я написал выше проблема была в том что я не вызывал после этого service.run_one().